# Why does create react app return an error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to create a React app, I just installed Node.js but the command `npx create-react-app .` doesn't work for some reason. Here is a screen shot from cmd:
variables [variables pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbtCs.png)
[image: variables pic]

Comment: It looks like your `PATH` and/or `COMSPEC` variables are messed up. Please write `set > variables.txt` into the terminal and then paste the resulting `variables.txt` file here. (You can of course strip personal info.)

Comment: By the way, dup of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56959262/react-npm-start-error-after-installing-mongodb/56959462), but no solution there yet either

Comment: Are you sure? A `variables.txt` should have been created in the folder you ran the command in. Please paste its contents here - edit your question to add it. (Feel free to remove personal information from it first.)

Comment: @CherryDT sorry my bad just update the post :)

Comment: Can you tell me how exactly you installed MongoDB? Do you remember where you got the installer from? It would be interesting to find out _why_ your `COMSPEC` was corrupted, so we can report it to the installer authors.

Comment: @CherryDT thnak you my friend for ur support i just give up i think im going to Format my disk

Answer (score 0):

Your `COMSPEC` variable is messed up.

- Press Win+R
- Enter `sysdm.cpl` and click OK
- Go to "advanced" tab
- Click button "environment variables"
- **If there is a `ComSpec` or `COMSPEC` entry in the *top* list:** Delete it
- **If there is a `ComSpec` or `COMSPEC` entry in the *bottom* list and it's not ending with `cmd.exe`:** Change it to `C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe`.
- Click OK
- Restart your computer

Answer (score -1):

You should add your app name you forgot that:

```
 npx create-react-app exercise
```

exercise: your app name

Comment: The error says otherwise. `.` is fine too, for current directory.

Comment: @jonrsharpe thank u for ur comment friend ! but im inside a folder i think i can do space and point to create an app inside the folder !